# How to modify text in SVG files

Tags: java, svg

I need to parse SVG files to find text in them modify it. Before jumping into XML parsing, I found [Apache's batik project](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). Since it claims to include a parser, I figured I could use it to achieve my goal, but I have not found a way to do it yet. The [documentation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/parsers.html) talks about parsing many things, but not text.

So, how do I change text in SVG files in Java?

Comment: If all I wanted to do was a search-and-replace on text within certain types of element, then I would consider using the `javax.xml.stream` classes instead of using a full-on SVG library.

Comment: Of course, if the application that created the SVG has computed the sizes of other non-text objects (e.g., a box surrounding text) based on the font metrics, then that's going to be a whole 'nother ball of wax.

Comment: I was considering that at first, but after looking at some SVG files I realized that there are some edge cases with formatting. For instance, the text in my files, after applying transformations, was inserted inside a nested tspan.

Comment: Formatting fidelity is not a big issue here, since it does not need to be perfect and the user will get visual feedback.